# How to access a number value in an array to add to a total?

Tags: flutter

I need to add up the total minutes in an array. The array includes a title and the minutes. How do I only access the minutes in the array to add up the sum of them? The array is not a set amount of values, you can add to the array.

```
List<Task> _allTasks = List<Task>();  
num sum = 0;
_allTasks.forEach((task){
    sum += sum + task.minutes;
    print(sum);
});

The array item looks like: {title: 'XXX', minutes: 15},
```

Output to be the total sum of minutes, eg: a total of the array (minutes only) = 45.

Comment: What is the problem with the code you have right now?

Comment: Did you added `Task` object in the array  `_allTasks ` ? Or before forEach loop simply print(_allTasks);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sum += sum + task.minutes;
```

should be

```
sum += task.minutes;
```

since `a+=b` in dart means `a=a+b`.

Rest of your code seems fine. Let us know if you are facing any other error.